# Explain how probSecond.calls equal to zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-decorators

```
def MainCount(f):
    def progFirst(*args,**kwargs):
        progFirst.calls+=1
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    progFirst.calls=0
    return progFirst
@MainCount
def progSecond(i):
    return i+1

@MainCount
def Count(i=0,j=1):
    return i*j+1
print(progSecond.calls)
for n in range(5):
    progSecond(n)
Count(j=0,i=1)
print(Count.calls)
```

Output :0
1

As per my understanding MainCount(probSecond) but I am not understant then how probSecond.calls equal to zero same in Count.calls also

Comment: What is the problem here?  You're printing `progSecond.calls` before you've ever called `progSecond`.  Then you're printing `Count.calls` after you've called `Count` once.  Your program is printing out exactly what it's supposed to.  Is the first print statement supposed to be later?

Comment: No,Could you explain how probSecond.calls is 0

Comment: p.s.  Calling the inner function of `MainCount` by the name `progFirst` is really confusing.  It really has no connection to the function you're calling `progSecond`.  Name it something like `wrapper` which explains what it really is.

Comment: You're printing out `probSecond.calls` before you've called `probSecond`.  Move that print statement to the end, and you'll see what you expect to see.  `.calls` counts the number of times the function has been already called.  It can't tell the future.

Perhaps you're misunderstanding what's happening.  What are you expecting, and why?

Comment: I got it. due to misunderstanding in Main count function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You Can See in MainCount function probFirst.Calls is attribute of function .When MainCount(probSecond) Now probSecond.calls is also attribute of MainCount function.

```
# A Python example to demonstrate that 
# decorators can be useful attach data 

# A decorator function to attach 
# data to func 
def attach_data(func): 
    func.data = 3
    return func 

@attach_data
def add (x, y): 
    return x + y 

# Driver code 

# This call is equivalent to attach_data() 
# with add() as parameter
print(add(2, 3)) 

print(add.data)
```